# How to check whether NFS Server in Ubuntu is installed or not?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I am trying to install NFS Server to my brand new Ubuntu machine and is about to follow [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html). But before that, is there any way to figure out whether it is already installed?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

**Update:-**

This is what I got after running this -

```
dpkg -la | grep nfs

ii  libnfsidmap2                     0.23-2                                            An nfs idmapping library
ii  nfs-common                       1:1.2.2-1ubuntu1                                  NFS support files common to client and server
```

And aptitude command gave me like this -

```
aptitude search nfs

p   fai-nfsroot                                                                                                    - Fully Automatic Installation nfsroot package
v   knfs                                                                                                           -
p   libfile-nfslock-perl                                                                                           - perl module to do NFS (or not) locking
p   libnfsidmap-dev                                                                                                - header files and docs for libnfsidmap
i A libnfsidmap2                                                                                                   - An nfs idmapping library
p   libyanfs-java                                                                                                  - Yet Another NFS - a Java NFS library
v   nfs-client                                                                                                     -
i   nfs-common                                                                                                     - NFS support files common to client and server
p   nfs-kernel-server                                                                                              - support for NFS kernel server
v   nfs-server                                                                                                     -
p   nfs4-acl-tools                                                                                                 - Commandline and GUI ACL utilities for the NFSv4 client
p   nfswatch                                                                                                       - Program to monitor NFS traffic for the console
p   p3nfs                                                                                                          - to mount the file systems on the Psion/Symbian PDA/Phone
p   unfs3                                                                                                          - User-space NFSv3 Server
p   unionfs-fuse                                                                                                   - Fuse implementation of unionfs
```

I tried netstat command as well -

```
netstat -tl | grep 2049
```

and nobody is listening to that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg -la | grep nfs
```

will list all packages that you have installed and whose name includes nfs.

```
aptitude search nfs
```

will tell you that the nfs server package is called `nfs-server`. Since you are not seeing that, I'd say you don't have it installed.

To be safe, also do:

```
netstat -tl | grep 2049
```

to check whether anyone is already listening on the nfs port.

Comment: this is what I got when I executed the above command - `ii  ftp                              0.17-23                                           The FTP client
`

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T: That was just an example.  For an NFS server, of course, you'd grep for "nfs".

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misread at first. Corrected my answer to nfs.

Comment: oops.. this is what I got - `ii  libnfsidmap2                     0.23-2                                            An nfs idmapping library
ii  nfs-common                       1:1.2.2-1ubuntu1                                  NFS support files common to client and server
`

Comment: I just have updated the question with more details and nobody is listening to that port as well which means I don't have it installed right?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T: Yeah, from the looks of it, it appears you don't have the server stuff installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the package's name, try `dpkg -l package-name`.  That should list the package (with two `i`s next to it) if it's installed, or give you an error if it isn't.

Ubuntu 13.10 (which is running in a VM here) calls its server package `nfs-kernel-server`.  (There might be other packages or other names on older versions; looks like it used to be called `knfs`.  But `nfs-kernel-server` is the recommended package.)

If you're using a decent package management program, though (like Synaptic, which i highly recommend), you can just type some stuff into a search box and it'll find matches for you -- at which point you can set it to install (unless you're installing from source, which i don't recommend if you can get by with the version Ubuntu includes with that release).

Comment: I don't know the package name.. I was about to install it by following the above article but thought to check it before installing it again..

Comment: It looks like `nfs-kernel-server` or (for older versions) `knfs`, plus whatever dependencies get added to the list, would be enough to give you a working NFS server.